# It's possible to allow sudo mode only for specific user?

Tags: bash, ssh, debian, sudo, public-key-encryption

I would like to **enable** sudo mode on my Debian server only for one **specific user**.

For example, I have two users. Daniel and Peter. Daniel has to have connect to ssh with pub key. Peter's connections to ssh will be possible with password, no key is required.
Daniel will be administrator user, so for him I would like to enable "su" command (sudo mode). For Peter not! *Peter will be only some kind of user that will testing something for gaming server.*

My question is, it is possible? Because I can't find anything useful on google :/ . Any ideas?

**Thank you for all answers!**

Daniel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `sudoers` file is what you should have a look at. There's a lengthy tutorial [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1132821). In essence, it allows you to specify which users should have access to the `sudo` command via their username.

A short example would be to add the following line to sudoers:

`%users ALL=(root) /usr/bin/find`

This would means that any member of the group `users` with any hostname (`ALL`) can only run the `find` program as a root user. They will not be able to run `rm` or any other command not specified. In contrast, something like

`%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL`

which is one of the defaults, allows any member of the `admin` group on any hostname to execute any program (the last `ALL`) as any user (the `ALL` in parentheses).

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want the sudoers file:

http://benaiah41.wordpress.com/2008/08/15/37/

"To give a user the ability to use the “sudo” command you must add them to the “sudoers” file.  Here’s how...."